# Drive not appearing when plugged in

Tags: mount, drive

I booted Ubuntu from my SSD. Then I plugged in my HDD into my Computer *after* linux had booted. As expected, it wasn't detected. How can I make my system detect it?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and DEsktop please.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo dmesg | tail -n 200 | grep -we 'sd?'` shortly after connecting the drive in question? Thanks.